# Retrieval of file from s3 fails with a The provided token has expired. Same file works with AWS CLI though

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an issue when I try to retrieve a file from s3. **I am able to connect to the s3 bucket as expected** but when I try to retrieve the file I get the below error.
**The credentials are being picked up from my `./aws/credentials`** and **I can download the same file from my local using the AWS CLI.**
Any ideas what might be wrong here?

```
Error: 
awsError
code = ExpiredToken
message = The provided token has expired.
statusCode = 400

Result, err := client.GetObject(&s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket:              &bucket,
        Key:                 &Key,
        ResponseContentType: aws.String("application/json"),
    })
    if err != nil {
        logger.Errorf("Unable to retrieve file the file", err.Error())
        return nil, http.StatusInternalServerError
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The expired token usually means that the **IAM role** which was assumed to perform some actions on S3 **has expired**. In this case, the rule should be re-assumed to get new temporary credentials for the assumed role.

When you use AWS CLI with credentials from `./aws/credentials` you usually use IAM user's credentials. These credentials, unlike for IAM roles, are **permanent**.

Which IAM role is used in your case, depends on how and where your code is executed. There are not too many details in the question, thus its difficult to speculate.

Comment: @Marcin- Well, in my case I am using the same `./aws/credentials` to make the call like I do with CLI. I am not declaring a separate credential set in my code. So I don't think they have expired but I will check again. Thanks!

Comment: @Contraboy The `./aws/credentials` can also contains roles. Maybe they expired. Similar error can also occur when the credentials for IAM user has been disabled or deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with all my AWS CLI calls too. For me, the solution was to remove (unset) the `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` environment variable (also `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`). On a previous project, I had to configure CLI access using SSO and exported `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` in my .zshenv file. I removed those explicitly. Another solution that worked for me also was to explicitly use `--profile default` which seems to short-circuit any ENV variables.